Celery and Celery Beat not reading Django Settings
I recently upgraded Django to 4.x from 3.x and all other deps as well. But since the upgrade celery and celery beat do not seem to recognize the settings that begin with CELERY_ and instead I had to provide broker URL as an ENV variable separately for celery to work.
But now celery-beat is not picking the right scheduler setting from DJANGO Settings and defaults to a file based scheduler.
Would appreciate any thoughts on this as been searching for an answer for a few days now.
For Celery I was able to add ENV variable and move forward but still would prefer a way to read the settings from Django
